# How data types should I keep for _id in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to store millions of entries into a mongob database. Now, I will have most of the queries on device_id ( which is a string something like aaff33raf-22daa-333fa ) Now, it would be a bad idea to store the object keeping device_id as primary key ( _id ) in it's current format. How about I map this string to a number and store it into a database.

So my question is - from the scalibility point of view ( Lots of reads and lots of writes ) how should I keep my _id field ? Integer or String ?

Comment: An integer _may_ save you query time, but a readable string could make or break any possibility of easily debugging. I can just imagine trying to find record `aaff33raf-22daa-333fa` manually when encoded to an integer in the database :-/

Comment: Why do you believe that it's a bad idea to keep it as a string in that format?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you pick an integer or a string as _id field does not make a whole lot of difference. It's an indexed field so pulling out by _id or updating by _id is not going to be a whole lot different.

Perhaps the size of the stored value is an issue, but the _id might be small compared to the whole document anyway... so likely not a problem either.

What is however important is readability and debugging and if you always refer to products like "aaff33raf-22daa-333fa" then you should keep doing that. Having it the same in the database keeps you sane.

Answer (score 0):

If your device IDs are immutable, then I would use the device ID as the document `_id`. If the device id might change and you do document to document references (like a foreign key), then I'd use `ObjectId`s and create a secondary index with the device ID.

Most importantly, if you can convert the device ID to a number, make sure it converts without loss.

While the example you provided wasn't obviously a valid number (it contained the letter `r`), if that was a typo and represented another character of the device ID, then the total number of bytes needed to store the device ID appears to be more than 8 bytes).

This exceeds the Int64 numeric type specified in [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) for example). (A double also only stores 8 bytes).

Given that, a string is a much more reasonable (and safe) key to be used as the document id. The performance difference will be minimally different from using a number. They'll both be indexed, and while searching a numeric index can be slightly faster (think nanoseconds), it shouldn't matter in typical workflows.

Also, during early application building, it's often useful to have access to the MongoDB shell, where having the DeviceIDs as strings I'd imagine would be more convenient than having them stored in an encoded format. (`db.devices.find({_id: 'aaff33raf-22daa-333fa' })`).